# Jhipster + Okta enabling OIDC and Server2Server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta

I am creating a JHipster project, and for authentication and authorization, I am using OKTA :) 
I used this tutorial to have Okta OpenID Connect on JHipster: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/20/oidc-with-jhipster and it's working like a charm.

I need to add **OAuth client_credentials** grant type to my JHipster app, to be able to talk to it from other Spring Boot applications.

When I started adding these capabilites to my application, I got only one grant type working, the OIDC or the client_credentials.

Can you give me an example how to enable the client_credentials?

Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear my tutorial worked for you! For client credentials, you might take a look at [Secure Server-to-Server Communication with Spring Boot and OAuth 2.0](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot).

Comment: Thank you @MattRaible your tutorial is great ! I tried the Server2Server tutorial, but I cannot make it work with OIDC activated :( I think that I am missing something which splits OIDC and Client_credentials.. 
Please help :(

Comment: You might need to add a `ResourceServerConfiguration` class that looks for the `Authorization` header. That's what I did to make things work with Ionic for JHipster. https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic/blob/master/generators/app/templates/src/main/java/package/config/ResourceServerConfiguration.java